# Проблема с DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Такая ситуация. Есть класс

```
public partial class HighlightTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public ObservableCollection<HighlightRule> HighlightRules
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<HighlightRule>)GetValue(HighlightRulesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightRulesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HighlightRules.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightRulesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightRules", typeof(ObservableCollection<HighlightRule>), typeof(HighlightTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<HighlightRule>()));

// Ну далее еще много чего тут
}
```

А вот класс `HighlightRule`

```
public class HighlightRule : DependencyObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Highlight> Highlights
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Highlight>)GetValue(HighlightsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Highlights.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Highlights", typeof(ObservableCollection<Highlight>), typeof(HighlightRule), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Highlight>()));

// Тут тоже много чего еще
}
```

вот как выглядит использование в XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:HighlightTextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                <local:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
                    <local:HighlightRule HightlightedText="{Binding Filter, Source={x:Reference thisWindow}}">
                        <local:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                            <local:HighlightBackgroung Brush="Yellow"/>
                        </local:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                    </local:HighlightRule>
                </local:HighlightTextBlock.HighlightRules>
            </local:HighlightTextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Ну и вроде все должно быть норм, но очень уж тормозило, поэтому я залез в отладку и увидел, что на каждое правило приходится подсветок ровно столько, сколько всего существует правил. То есть в данном случае по числу элементов коллекции. Может, я не правильно как то пользуюсь свойствами зависимостей, потому что каждое правило ссылается на одни и те же подсветки (хотя как видно из xamla, каждому правилу соответствует одна подстветка в данном случае).

**UPD:**

Вот проект по примеру VladD

[скачать](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4brnWIbEoFOcERDeTRtdE9ORlk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема вот где:

```
new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Highlight>())
```

У вас получается, что вы *один и тот же экземпляр* `ObservableCollection<Highlight>` делаете значением по умолчанию свойства `Highlights` для *всех* экземпляров `HighlightRule`! Обычно эта проблема незаметна, если ваше свойство — value type, т. к. он при копировании клонируется, в отличие от ссылочного типа.

Делайте так:

```
public class HighlightRule : DependencyObject
{
    public HighlightRule()
    {
        Highlights = new ObservableCollection<Highlight>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Highlight> Highlights
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Highlight>)GetValue(HighlightsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Highlights", typeof(ObservableCollection<Highlight>), typeof(HighlightRule));

    // Тут тоже много чего еще
}
```

---

То же касается и `HighlightTextBlock`, разумеется.

Comment: Я догадывался, что проблема именно в этом и пытался сделать так вот ,как вы подсказали, но в этом случае все мое наполнение в xaml коде ушло в никуда. Я не знаю почему. По идее должен вызваться конструктор, создаться свойство, потом наполниться из xaml. но на практике у меня все коллекции в этом случае получаются равны null.

Comment: @iRumba: Странно. Будем подумать.

Comment: @iRumba: Странно, у меня работает. А можете состряпать воспроизводящий пример?

Comment: Ссылка для скачивания в вопросе. Visual Studio 2015

Comment: А хотя.... вроде все норм... Это я вчера видать устал уже. Проблема в другом теперь, но с этим я уже разберусь сам :)

Comment: @iRumba: О, ну слава богу, а то было совсем странно. Удачи вам!